# Get mat-step inner contents angular material

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am using angular material `stepper` I want to get `mat-step` inner contents when stepper `(selectionChange)` event fired.

**Ts**

```
import { StepperSelectionEvent } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-stepper',
  templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./stepper.component.css']
})
export class StepperComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  handleSelectionChange(event: StepperSelectionEvent){
    // I want selected mat-step inner contents here. 
  }
}
```

**Html Template**

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="false" #stepper (selectionChange)="handleSelectionChange($event)">
  <mat-step label="Step 1">
      <app-form></app-form>
      <p>testing</p>
      <!-- I want <app-form> component and other contents when (selctionChange) event fired-->
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step  label="Step 2">
    <reactiveForm></reactiveForm>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    <p>You are now done.</p>
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```